# What is the function 'selectifr' from Ox in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ox

I was wondering if somebody could tell me which is the equivalent of the function `selectifr` from `Ox` in Matlab ?

```
for(i = 1; i <= sizeof(vdates); i = i+1)
    daily_file = selectifr([bid,ask], dates .== vdates[i]);
    if empty continue
    save daily_file contract_name + "_" + sprint(vdates[i]) ;
```

How do I translate this program into `Matlab`?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used `Ox` but after a quick google search going from the [docs](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/system/man/ox-2.00/oxstd.htm#selectifr).

```
The selectifr function returns an s x n matrix, 
selecting only those rows from ma which have at least one non-zero element 
in the corresponding row of mifr.
```

Where in the function `selectifr(const ma, const mifr);`

```
ma = m x n matrix to select from

mifr = m x q boolean matrix specifying rows to select
```

So essentially you are picking specify dates of the [bid,ask]. In term's of matlab, I think an [intersect](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html) of [union](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/union.html?searchHighlight=union) might be what you need here

Comment: I have a intraday 5 minutes data and need to split 900,000 rows(bid,ask, data)in either a vector nxm(n rows(bid,ask),m columns(here I know there are 1259 days))..Or either a vector for each day that should take the prices(bid,ask) acording to the dates..I cannot use the function reshape because in one day I have more observations and in another less.(I don't know which are the days when the obervations are not the same).

Comment: @MarinelaFinta what format do you have the data stored and how are you loading it?

Comment: So I have a nx1(n=935039) vector of the data like this: 734142 734142 734142 734142 734142 734143 734143 734143 734143 734143 734143 734143 734143 734143.. Then a vector with prices:1115.80000000000 1115.40000000000 1116 1116 1115.80000000000 1115.70000000000 1115.70000000000 1115.40000000000 1115.60000000000 1115.60000000000 1115.70000000000 1115.60000000000 1115.80000000000 1115.80000000000 1115.70000000000 correpondig to each date...

Comment: There is no way to split them either in one matrix with I don't know how many rows(which are gonna be the prices for each day) but I know the number of columns 1260(which are the days I have).. Or if not just to make 1260 vectors(nx1) with the prices for each day.